# How to convert List to numpy Array

Tags: python, list, numpy, tensorflow, nlp

Here's the link to collab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wftAvDu_Wu2Y9ahgI1Z1FLciUH5MnSJ9

train_labels = ['GovernmentSchemes', 'GovernmentSchemes', 'GovernmentSchemes', 'GovernmentSchemes', 'CropInsurance']

```
training_label_seq = np.array(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels))
```

output coming :

```
[list([3]) list([3]) list([3]) ... list([2]) list([5]) list([1])]
```

expected output :

```
[[3] [3] [3] .. [2] [5]...]
```

```
num_epochs = 30
history = model.fit(train_padded, training_label_seq, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(validation_padded, validation_label_seq))
```

Error =>  ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)

Comment: what is the logic between the input and output? and how can `label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences` be reproduced ?

Comment: Yes, this code is a bit incomplete.  label_tokenizer - is this from TensorFlow?  If so, this should have been included.  The code, as it stands, is a snippet, and can't be run.  Posting a minimal reproducible example is important.

Comment: Output after using -- np.array([[x] for x in training_label_seq])
 [list([3])]
 [list([3])]
 [list([3])]]

Comment: Where do we get `'kcc_maharashtra.csv'`?

Comment: @FrederikBode by uploading it ! available at data.gov.in

Comment: Couldn't find it. Can you provide a donwload link?

Comment: @Anirudh_k07 - I have updated the answer as per our discussion and identified the error in the program. Kindly have the look in the answer. Have updated the answer at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your issue using the below code -

**Code to recreate the issue -**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

label_tokenizer = Tokenizer()

# Fit on a text 
fit_text = "Tensorflow warriors are awesome people"
label_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(fit_text)

# Training Labels
train_labels = "Tensorflow warriors are great people"
training_label_list = np.array(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels))

# Print the 
print(training_label_list)
print(type(training_label_list))
print(type(training_label_list[0]))
```

**Output -**

```
2.2.0
[list([9]) list([1]) list([10]) list([5]) list([3]) list([2]) list([11])
 list([7]) list([3]) list([6]) list([]) list([6]) list([4]) list([2])
 list([2]) list([12]) list([3]) list([2]) list([5]) list([]) list([4])
 list([2]) list([1]) list([]) list([4]) list([2]) list([1]) list([])
 list([]) list([2]) list([1]) list([4]) list([9]) list([]) list([8])
 list([1]) list([3]) list([8]) list([7]) list([1])]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'list'>
```

**Solution -**

1. Replacing `np.array` with `np.hstack` will fix your problem. Your `model.fit()` should work fine now.
2. Else if you are looking for the expected output as in your question,  `training_label_list = label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels)` will give you a list of list. You can use `np.array([np.array(i) for i in training_label_list])` to convert to array of array. This works only if your list of lists contains lists with same number of elements.

**np.hstack Code -** Code for Point number 1 in solution.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

label_tokenizer = Tokenizer()

# Fit on a text 
fit_text = "Tensorflow warriors are awesome people"
label_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(fit_text)

# Training Labels
train_labels = "Tensorflow warriors are great people"
training_label_list = np.hstack(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels))

# Print the 
print(training_label_list)
print(type(training_label_list))
print(type(training_label_list[0]))
```

**Output -**

```
2.2.0
[ 9.  1. 10.  4.  2.  3. 11.  7.  2.  5.  5.  6.  3.  3. 12.  2.  3.  4.
  6.  3.  1.  3.  1.  6.  9.  8.  1.  2.  8.  7.  1.]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

**Expected output as in question -** Code for Point number 2 in solution.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

label_tokenizer = Tokenizer()

# Fit on a text 
fit_text = "Tensorflow warriors are awesome people"
label_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(fit_text)

# Training Labels
train_labels = "Tensorflow warriors are great people"
training_label_list = label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels)

# Print 
print(training_label_list)
print(type(training_label_list))
print(type(training_label_list[0]))

# To convert elements to array
training_label_list = np.array([np.array(i) for i in training_label_list])

# Print
print(training_label_list)
print(type(training_label_list))
print(type(training_label_list[0]))
```

**Output -**

```
2.2.0
[[9], [1], [10], [4], [2], [3], [11], [7], [2], [5], [], [5], [6], [3], [3], [12], [2], [3], [4], [], [6], [3], [1], [], [], [3], [1], [6], [9], [], [8], [1], [2], [8], [7], [1]]
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
[array([9]) array([1]) array([10]) array([4]) array([2]) array([3])
 array([11]) array([7]) array([2]) array([5]) array([], dtype=float64)
 array([5]) array([6]) array([3]) array([3]) array([12]) array([2])
 array([3]) array([4]) array([], dtype=float64) array([6]) array([3])
 array([1]) array([], dtype=float64) array([], dtype=float64) array([3])
 array([1]) array([6]) array([9]) array([], dtype=float64) array([8])
 array([1]) array([2]) array([8]) array([7]) array([1])]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

---

**Update 2/6/2020** - [Anirudh_k07](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13647695/anirudh-k07), As per our discussion, I had a look into your program and you are getting below error in `model.fit()` after using `np.hstack` for labels.

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 41063
  y sizes: 41429
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

This error you are getting is because few of the labels have special characters like `-` and `/`. Thus on performing `np.hstack(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels)`, they are creating additional rows. You can print list of unique `train_labels` by using `print(set(train_labels))`.

**Here is gist of what I am trying to say -**

```
# These Labels have special character
train_labels = ['Bio-PesticidesandBio-Fertilizers','Old/SenileOrchardRejuvenation']
training_label_seq = np.hstack(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels))
print("Two labels are converted to Five :",training_label_seq)

# These Labels are fine
train_labels = ['SoilHealthCard', 'PostHarvestPreservation', 'FertilizerUseandAvailability']
training_label_seq = np.hstack(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels))
print("Three labels are remain three :",training_label_seq)
```

**Output -**

```
Two labels are converted to Five : [17 18 19 51 52]
Three labels are remain three : [20 36  5]
```

So kindly do the proper preprocessing and eliminate these special characters in `train_labels` and then use `np.hstack(label_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_labels))` on labels. Your `model.fit()` should work fine after that.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Anirudh_k07 - Does this answer your question?

Comment: Using 2nd method => Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).

Comment: Using Method 1 my shape is changing & the dimensions are no longer matching

Comment: As we mentioned in the answer, Method 1 is the proper way to use in `model.fit()`. Method 2 is just mentioned as you stated the expected output in your question. Input shape is altogether a different problem that depends on shape of your input data and input shape mentioned in first layer. Do share those information, so that we can help.

Comment: Are you doing `pad_sequences` after `Tokenizer` to pad sequences to the same length in input? Would recommend you to look into this link - https://charon.me/posts/tf/tf3/ to understand better the Tokenization and Text Data Preparation for `model.fit()`.

Comment: please go through the collab link. Pad_sequences can be generated after tokenization!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215113/discussion-between-tensorflow-warriors-and-anirudh-k07).

Comment: @Anirudh_k07 - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.